# how to set an invisible status using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## Code

```
async def shutdown(ctx):

    if ctx.message.author.name == 'LouieMartin':

        await ctx.send('Shutting down...')

        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.invisible)

        quit()
```

## Problem

The problem is the `await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.invisible)`.

## Problem solution

There are no problem solutions that I can think of.

Comment: Any errors/tracebacks? What's the current result?

Comment: There are no kinds of errors/tracebacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it would be...

```
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
```

instead of...

```
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.invisible)
```

This worked for my bot.